# How do I add a growl to an audio file of me speaking?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, audacity, depth

I'm trying to use Audacity to make a "voice of God" sound with an audio file of me reading some sentence. I've already added the following effects:

**Echo**

```
Delay time (seconds): 0.25
Decay factor: 0.5
```

**Pitch**

```
Pitch: F9 (11025 Hz)
High quality stretching: On
```

**Reverb**

```
Room size (%): 100
Pre-delay (ms): 10
Reverberance (%): 100
Damping (%): 100
Tone Low (%): 100
Tone High (%): 100
Wet Gain (dB): -1
Dry Gain (dB): -1
Stereo Width (%): 0
```

Is there a way to add a low growl when some of the words are said?

Side note - if you have any other ideas to make this sound more powerful and scary, I'm all ears!!!

Comment: Have you tried adding an octave divider - one, or even two octaves below will really beef this up.

Answer (score 2):

Well I would suggest using a VST plugin if you're familiar with that. I wrote down the ones I'm using for you with links:

[RoVee](https://link.hiphopmakers.com/za7h/)

[Clownfish Voice Changer](https://link.hiphopmakers.com/Clownfish/)

[Graillon 2 Live Voice Changer](https://link.hiphopmakers.com/zuw9)

[MAutoPitch](https://link.hiphopmakers.com/MAutoPitch)

[GForm](https://www.gvst.co.uk/beta.htm)

[Pitchproof](https://link.hiphopmakers.com/Pitchproof)

[KeroVee](https://link.hiphopmakers.com/KeroVee/)

I Hope this can be of any help for you, even though I'm 11 days late to see your question. :D